# Magento 2 - How was the static block added above contact-us form in magento sample data?

Tags: magento2, contact-us, sample-data

I just installed a fresh magento 2.4.1 with sample data. I noticed that the contact us site shows a static block `contact-us-info` above the form.

But I could not figure out how that block was added.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is created as a widget.

```
Content -> Elements: Widgets -> Contact us info
```